# VirtualProtect With PAGE_GUARD Not Working With Local Variables

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, memory

This works as expected. A `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` is raised.

```
int main()
{
    DWORD oldp;
    DWORD *pdp = new DWORD;
    *pdp = 0;
    if (!VirtualProtect(pdp, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &oldp))
        return 1;
    *pdp = 1000;
    return 0;
}
```

However when this almost identical code is run the program exits with no exception.

```
int main()
{
    DWORD oldp;
    DWORD pd = 0;
    DWORD *pdp = &pd;
    if (!VirtualProtect(pdp, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &oldp))
        return 1;
    *pdp = 1000;
    return 0;
}
```

Both programs `exited with code 0`, so `VirtualProtect` is completing successfully. Why then, in the second example, is there no exception raised when I attempt to access the guarded memory?

**Edit:**

Running this causes an access violation; thus proving Ton's hypothesis.

```
int main()
{
    DWORD oldp;
    DWORD pd = 0;
    DWORD *pdp = &pd;
    if (!VirtualProtect(pdp, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_NOACCESS, &oldp))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good question. Can you `VirtualProtect` the stack?

Comment: It seems that I can because if, in the second example, I call `VirtualProtect` with `PAGE_NOACCESS` instead of `PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD` I am given an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` when I attempt to dereference `pdp`.

Comment: The stack uses guard pages to determine when it needs to be expanded.  The access violation occurs, but is caught and handled by Windows, you never see it.  (And of course you're not supposed to be messing with permissions on address space that doesn't belong to you in the first place.)

Comment: Per [Thread Stack Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774.aspx): "*The system commits additional pages from the reserved stack memory as they are needed, until either the stack reaches the reserved size minus one page (**which is used as a guard page to prevent stack overflow**) or the system is so low on memory that the operation fails.*"

Comment: And also [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563/): "***The dynamic growth of the stack is performed via guard pages**: Just past the last valid page on the stack is a guard page. When the stack grows into the guard page, a guard page exception is raised, which the default exception handler handles by committing a new stack page and setting the next page to be a guard page... **the guard page exceptions are handled entirely within the kernel. User-mode exception handlers cannot see or intercept them***"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your second example you set a PAGE_GUARD on the memory page used by your application stack. After the VirtuaProtect succeeds, the *first* access to that page will raise an exception. That first access is not done by the '*pdp = 1000' code. Likely this is access already done in the VirtualProtect function. If this handles this (specific) exception gracefully it will explain the behaviour that you see.